# Get the Selected value from the Drop down box in PHP

Tags: php

I am populating a Drop Down Box using the following code.

```
<select id="select_catalog">
<?php 
$array_all_catalogs = $db->get_all_catalogs();
foreach($array_all_catalogs as $array_catalog){?>
<option value="<?= $array_catalog['catalog_key'] ?>"><?= array_catalog['catalog_name'] ?></option>
```

Now how can I get the selected option value using `PHP` (I have the code to get the selected item using `Javascript` and `jQuery`) because I want the selected value to perform a query in database.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you very much...

Comment: You are just showing us the code for rendering the select box. Show us your jquery code for posting back to the server. If you do not need to use AJAX, you can simply access the selected value in your `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set a name on the `<select>` tag like so:

```
<select name="select_catalog" id="select_catalog">
```

You can get it in php with this:

```
$_POST['select_catalog'];
```

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't you just pass the  a name attribute and wrap it in a form?

```
<form id="form" action="do_stuff.php" method="post">
    <select id="select_catalog" name="select_catalog_query">
    <?php <<<INSERT THE SELECT OPTION LOOP>>> ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

And then look for `$_POST['select_catalog_query']` ?

Comment: when i use $_POST['select_catalog_query'] I am getting an error: 'undefined index in line blah blah'

Comment: Are you actually submiting the form before looking for it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a `name` attribute on your `<select />` element, and then use it from the `$_POST` or `$_GET` (depending on how you transmit data) arrays in PHP. Be sure to sanitize user input, though.

Answer (score 0):

Posting it from my project.

```
<select name="parent" id="parent"><option value="0">None</option>
<?php
 $select="select=selected";
 $allparent=mysql_query("select * from tbl_page_content where parent='0'");
 while($parent=mysql_fetch_array($allparent))
   {?>
   <option value="<?= $parent['id']; ?>" <?php if( $pageDetail['parent']==$parent['id'] ) { echo($select); }?>><?= $parent['name']; ?></option>
  <?php 
   }
  ?></select>
```