# how to get the selected option in value in php

Tags: php, dropdown

Please guide me to get the selected option in a drop-down to the PHP variable

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-order-type"><?php echo $entry_order_type; ?></label>
    <select name="filter_order_type" id="input-order-type" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">FB Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Direct Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Khathija's Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Ameer's Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Saheed's Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Nada's Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Henath's Orders</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>">Noha's Orders</option>
    </select>
    <?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>
</div>
```

I need the selected value to be assigned in `$filter_order_type`

Comment: you can get it as $selectOption = $_POST['filter_order_type']; on server side.

Comment: Do you have any condition ?

Comment: Or use jQuery to select the values

Comment: It looks like you are using same **value** in every option.`<?php echo $filter_order_type; ?>`

Comment: how you are storing/trying to store value as `name`  or `id` ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i need to happen in on-time. if user select any options it will be visible as text like 'you have selected this options '

Comment: @C2486 as name dude, help me

Comment: @B.Desai can you please correct it to me??

Comment: @Askxah What is `$filer_order_tyoe`? Is it an array or something? Please edit post and add the code to show what `$filter_order_type` is

Comment: Then you should use jquery.

Comment: share the value of `$entry_order_type` and `$filter_order_type` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Selected value from the Drop down box in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207671/get-the-selected-value-from-the-drop-down-box-in-php)

Comment: So you want to select an option, Direct Orders, and then Direct Orders should be displayed under the dropdown, right?

Comment: @C2486  $filter_order_type is just a variable , $entry_order_type is also an variable it retried value from another php file

Comment: @Celebrombore absolutely yes dude

Comment: @Ask xah Hmhm I dont think that this is possible in real time without submitting a form first or using JS, but i am no PHP Pro ;)

Comment: @Celebrombore  without form it's possible in jQuery. With form only it's possible in PHP. I have added both ways in my answer.You can check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a form to submit what the user has selected. When the user submits the form the selected value will be posted and taken into the variable `$entry_order_type`. I think this is what you are expecting. Hope it helps. :)

```
<?php
$entry_order_type ="Select order type from the list and press the submit button";
if(isset($_POST['filter_order_type'])){
   $entry_order_type = $_POST['filter_order_type'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input-order-type"><?php echo $entry_order_type; ?></label>

    <select name="filter_order_type" id="input-order-type" class="form-control">

      <option value=""></option>

      <option value="FB Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="FB Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >FB Orders</option>
      <option value="Direct Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Direct Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Direct Orders</option>
      <option value="Khathija's Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Khathija's Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Khathija's Orders</option>
      <option value="Ameer's Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Ameer's Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Ameer's Orders</option>
      <option value="Saheed's Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Saheed's Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Saheed's Orders</option>
      <option value= "Nada's Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Nada's Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Nada's Orders</option>
      <option value="Henath's Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Henath's Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Henath's Orders</option>
      <option value="Noha's Orders" <?php if($entry_order_type=="Noha's Orders"){echo "selected";} ?> >Noha's Orders</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: your answer is almost correct but, i need after clicking the submit button. dropdown option should be as selected not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can be done in PHP is by submitting the form by user and then reading the submitted value by using `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable. This is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17139538/4264695

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your default value with `php` value as below.
For e.g.

```
<option value="your_default_value" <?php if(isset($filter_order_type)){ if($filter_order_type == 'your_default_value'){ echo 'selected'; } } ?> >FB Orders</option>
```

You have to set like this for all the `option` and check it with your default value by comparison with your `php` value.